# kivy to run python code with threads and matplotlib

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, kivy

I have created this python code:

```
import threading
from drawnow import drawnow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time

stop = []
timer = []
times = []

plt.ion()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        c = 30
        print 'TIMER START'
        while not stop:
            timer.append(c)
            time.sleep(1)
            c -= 1
        print 'TIMER STOP', c, ","
        times.append(c)
        return c

def makefig():
    #plt.ylim(0,5)
    plt.plot(times, 'ro-', label='testgraph')
    plt.grid(True)

def main_loop():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
        if i == 7:
            i = 0
        yield i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = main_loop()
    for x in z:
        print x
        print times
        drawnow(makefig)
        if x == 2:
            m = MyThread()
            m.start()
        if x == 5:
            stop.append('a')
        if x == 6:
            stop.pop(0)
            timer = []
```

it let's me to return numbers from 0 to 7 with different time values between generating new number and run countdown timer between values 2 & 5 and append counter value to a list. I am plotting list values in matplotlib.

Question:

how to execute this code with kivy so kivy displays the counter value and not terminal, so kivy plot the value and not matplotlib ?

---

EDIT:

This is my code so far but I can not work out the same threads functionality:

```
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


import threading
from drawnow import drawnow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time


class MyThread(BoxLayout):
    #stop = []
    #timer = []
    #times = []
    i = NumericProperty(0)

    def run(self):
        c = 30
        print 'TIMER START'
        while not stop:
            timer.append(c)
            time.sleep(1)
            c -= 1
        print 'TIMER STOP', c, ","
        times.append(c)
        return c

    def main_loop(self):

        while True:
            self.ids.lbl.text = "{}".format(self.i)
            print self.i
            self.i += 1
            time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
            if self.i == 7:
                self.i = 0

    def read_it(self):
        threading.Thread(target = self.main_loop).start()
        print 'started'
        if self.i == 2:
            print "Counter start"
        if self.i == 5:
            print "Counter stop"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('thread.kv')
        return MyThread()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

EDIT2:

I have forgoten to show thread.kv file:

```
<MyThread>:
    Button:
        text: "use thread"
        on_release: root.read_it()
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: "Numbers"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plotting there is [Graph](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph) in the Garden, which will make your life easier if you don't want to play with graphic instructions alone - it's a nice practice though.

In Kivy you can easily access e.g. `.text` property in widgets that has this property i.e. `Label`, `TextInput` and some others.

```
mylabel = Label(text=<string>)
mylabel.text = <string 2>
```

What you are asking is basically "convert python to kivy" because I see nothing that you tried except python-only code - not nice and you won't learn kivy. For this I recommend you:

- [kivy.org tutorials](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html)
- inclement's [tutorial](https://github.com/inclement/kivy-tutorials) and [Crash Course](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/)(videos)
- [Python Threads with Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application)

**Edit:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<MyThread>:
    Button:
        text: "use thread"
        on_release: root.run_thread()
    Button:
        text: "check values"
        on_release: root.read_it()
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: "Numbers"
''')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
import threading
import random
import time

class MyThread(BoxLayout):
    i = NumericProperty(0)

    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            self.ids.lbl.text = "{}".format(self.i)
            print self.i
            self.i += 1
            time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
            if self.i == 7:
                self.i = 0

    def run_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target = self.main_loop).start()
    def read_it(self):
        print 'started'
        if self.i == 2:
            print "Counter start"
        if self.i == 5:
            print "Counter stop"

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyThread()
MyApp().run()
```

You can also go for [on_* functions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname):

```
def on_i(self, *args):
    print i # when i changes
```

Edit2: I removed `run()`, because it wasn't used anyway in that particular code. You want to separate Thread.start() from any code if you want to call the function again, otherwise you'll start other Thread if you click more than once on that button. Test it now.

Comment: Hi, I have just edited my question with the code I have created so far but I am doing something wrong because I can not get threads working ... I can not print 'Counter start', 'Counter stop' ...

Comment: You don't call `MyThread.read_it()`, so no such thing will happen. Try to make a `Button` and call that function `on_release` of that button, it should print(to the console).

Comment: hi, I call it...I use thread.kv in which I start read_it() once button pressed. Sorry, I have just forgotten to show thread.kv file.

Comment: Then it works for me. Prints both `0started` and then the numbers. But beware, you want to stop the `Thread` in [`App.on_stop`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_stop) or it will leave the console open.

Comment: It does not... you want to print 'Counter start' if i ==2 and 'Counter stop' if i == 5.

Comment: Try clicking it multiple times. It works exactly as you coded it. The thing is - you call those `if`s only when you press the button, which you pressed probably only once(in the beginning) and what the button does it that it _starts **main_loop()** and executes the rest. Then the function ends and only **main_loop()** is being executed. It's also called only once, but because of the `while` it'll loop forever, so it may seem that the function is called more than one time. You want that part from *read_it* inside your *main_loop*.

Comment: I believe once I press the button I start read_it function and start main_loop that stucks in while True so I do not jump out of while so I can not come back to read_it and run both functions simultanously using thread as per my original python code.

Comment: No, because you still don't call `read_it` inside your `main_loop`, which is why I wrote that you should move those parts into `main_loop` and therefore with `read_it` only start the Thread.